# Folium colormap not being applied to geojson data

Tags: python, pandas, leaflet, geojson

I am using Folium to create a map which has a set of polygon that need to be colored based on other data. When I try to do so they just appear black and the specified colormap is not applied.
The legend shows the correct color bar.

```
map_1 = folium.Map(location=[cy, cx], zoom_start=8,)

#add origin marker
#map_1.polygon_marker(location=[cy,cx], popup=str(r))

map_1.geo_json(geo_path='p.json', data=my_data, data_out='data.json',
               columns=['id', 'value'],
               threshold_scale=[0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0],
               key_on='feature.id',
               fill_color='YlGn', fill_opacity=1.0, line_opacity=0.2, reset=True)

map_1.create_map(path=path, plugin_data_out=True)
```

my_data looks like following

```
      id     value
0   1793  0.162983
1   1796  0.247965
2   1797  0.456300
3   1798  0.840878
4   1799  0.612632
5   1800  0.540876
6   1801  0.792621
7   1802  0.302303
8   1803  0.534493
9   1804  0.306899
10  1805  0.208577
11  1806  0.904390
12  1807  0.127597
13  1808  0.567768
14  1809  0.021931
15  1810  0.084022
```

PS: *Could someone create and add a tag for Folium*

Comment: I found something odd in my_data, those ID's are not present in geojson, no wonder the color scale is not applied. I will post back after further debugging.

Comment: Did you by any chance find a solution for this? I have the exact same problem. Including the legend that shows, but nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem with GeoJson.

This is what worked for me : It seems like you need to have the color variable in your code present.

Try this :

```
map_1 = folium.Map(location=[cy, cx], zoom_start=8,)

#add origin marker
#map_1.polygon_marker(location=[cy,cx], popup=str(r))

map_1.geo_json(geo_path='p.json', data=my_data, data_out='data.json',
               columns=['id', 'value'],
               threshold_scale=[0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0],
               key_on='feature.id',
               color='YlGn', fill_opacity=1.0, line_opacity=0.2, reset=True)

map_1.create_map(path=path, plugin_data_out=True)
```